# How can I fire a function only when an *ngFor has finished, without using any listed-component

Tags: angular, ngfor

Template:

```
<li class="row" *ngFor="let item of items;" (click)="setSelectedItem(item)"></li>
```

I need to fire an event only when last `<li>` has been listed.
I've read some other post, but people use component rather than `<li>`, which I'd prefer.

Comment: Do you only want the event the first time `*ngFor` renders the list or also on later updates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular2 lifecycle hooks for this.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

> ngAfterViewInit()
>
> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views.
>
> Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().
>
> A component-only hook.

If you want to run code after your component variables change, not when initialising a component, then please look at the "AfterView" or "OnChange" part of the lifecycle hooks.

---

### Edit 1

If you wish to intercept ngfor, then you can use the local variable "last" in ngFor. Docs below.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: I tried with OnChange, but it's nothing to do with OnChange or AfterView, the component generates a list after the user click on a button.

Comment: Edited my answer.